# JavaFX table not accepting data

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

This is my class for table view (not FX class its my own for data)

```
class tableView {

SimpleIntegerProperty profit;
SimpleDoubleProperty probabilty;

public tableView(int profit, double prob) {
    this.profit = new SimpleIntegerProperty(profit);
    this.probabilty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(prob);
}
}
```

and My code for event handler and other controller is :

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int noOfStream = Integer.parseInt(steamsize.getText());
    double sellingPrice = Double.valueOf(sell.getText());
    double costPrice = Double.valueOf(cost.getText());
    int quantity = Integer.valueOf(Quantity.getText());
    double discountPrice = Double.valueOf(discount.getText());
    int randomStart = Integer.parseInt(RandStart.getText());
    int randomEnd = Integer.parseInt(RandEnd.getText());

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfStream; i++) {
        int dem = r.nextInt(randomEnd - randomStart) + randomStart;
        int profit = profitCacl(sellingPrice, costPrice, quantity, discountPrice, dem);
        double prob = cal.probCal(profitArray, profit);
      //  System.out.println(profit);
      //  System.out.println(prob);
        if (prob == 0.1) {
            profitArray.add(new tableView(profit, prob));
        } 
    }

}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    cal = new methodsForCal();
    choice.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Normal",
            "Poison",
            "Uniform"
    ));

    Profit.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("profit"));
    Probabilty.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("probabilty"));

    profitArray = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    tableForReading.setItems(profitArray);

}
```

Now my issue is My data is not inserting in the data ! as it is printing on the console as good as i want !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PropertyValueFactory` requires the item class to contain methods that return the property or getters for the property value. You need to add methods `profitProperty` and `probabiltyProperty` to `tableView`, that return the properties.

Alternatively you could use your own `cellValueFactory`s:

```
// assuming TableColumn declarations with type parameters
Profit.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<tableView, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Number> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<tableView, Number> param) {
        return param.getValue().profit;
    }
});
Probabilty.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<tableView, Number>, ObservableValue<Number>>() {

    @Override
    public ObservableValue<Number> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<tableView, Number> param) {
        return param.getValue().probability;
    }
});
```

Mode info can be found here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm

Comment: lembda expression error is given when I use your way @fabian

Comment: lambda expression not expected here

Comment: @user3163224: That seems unlikely, since the type of `cellValueFactory` is annotated with `@FunctionalInterface`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/util/Callback.html. You are using Java 8 aren't you?

Comment: @user3163224: I've updated the code to use anonymus classes instead of lambdas. This should work in versions>= 5 <8 too

Comment: @user3163224 Edit your question so that the code for the controller includes the declarations of the `TableColumn`s.

Comment: It doesn't work still ! @fabian when I put your code in my project

Comment: @user3163224: Unfortunately I won't be able to help you any further without a [mcve]. But equality for `double`s seems unlikely for random values.